# "Error": "Unrecognized field: 0 when triyng to findBy ASC ORM/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm not sure what syntax I'm missing here but when I try to Oder my Database field by ASC or DESC

I Keep getting:

```
"Error": "Unrecognized field: 0
```

Is my Syntax Wrong ? Do I have to add another field name ?

Can't wrap my head around it.

Here is the Repository function:

```
return $this->findBy([
    'user' => $user,
    ['createDate' => 'asc']
]);
```

Here is the Enitity Column:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime|null
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="create_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private ?\DateTime $createDate;
```

I tried using createDate and create_date none work.

Comment: Whatever the reason for this error, it's not clear what the problem is, which is the fault of the Symfony source editors. I'm on an older project and going by the book (yes, using the proper property name and casing), yet getting this cryptic error with no indication of what to do about it other than surfing through more StackOverflow answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidently nested the second parameter within the first (it has index `0`):

```
return $this->findBy([ // within this array keys should be fieldnames
    'user' => $user,   // key 'user', value $user
    ['createDate' => 'asc'] // key 0, value array
]);
```

This should be called passing two separate array parameters:

```
return $this->findBy(['user' => $user], ['createDate' => 'asc']);
```